# Put categories on PAGE url wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, categories

Ok, here is the thing I have already added the categories to the pages (with the help of a plug-in, it's called [Add category to pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-category-to-pages/)) and so now I want to **change the URL** to display the categories (that is to say I want my pages to have this estructure: **mysite.com/%categories%/%page_name%** right now it has his structure: *mysite.com/%page_name%*), I have tried to google it but I can't find a straight answer. So if anyone has some resources (*tutorials*, articles) or some idea (if it's not to much to ask with code examples) on how to achieve this it would be fantastic. (And believe me, I'm asking as my last resource)

Comment: You're talking about posts, right, not pages?

Comment: nope, I'm talking about PAGES not posts.

Comment: Pages doesn't have categories by default. If you installed some plugin you may want to give some more context here.

Comment: it's just funny you are talking about same thing :)) posts & pages are just different post_type, they both are posts :)))

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily with "Page Parent" option available in WordPress.

Steps To create a subpage

1. Go to Administration > Pages > Add New screen.
2. In the right menu, click the **“Page Parent/No Parent”** drop-down/page attribute widget. The drop-down menu contains a list of all the Pages already created for your website.
3. Select the appropriate parent page from the drop-down menu to make the current Page a child Page.
4. Add content to the subpage.
5. Click Publish when ready.

Output - https://example.com/asia/india/

More Info. - [Wordpress Subpage Permalink](https://wordpress.org/support/article/pages/#to-create-a-subpage)

Answer (score 0):

well you can do this for categories and products from permalink setting, but if you want to manipulate the page url according to yourself then you need to create an blank page with the prescribed name whichever you want to insert, i.e, if you want to insert amazon within the url then create an url with name of amazon, and put the other url's under this parent page.

This way your url will look like
http://example.com/amazon/page_name

Answer (score -1):

Unable to post as comment so directly posting it in an answer, in WordPress you can have custom URL. After you logged I'm as admin under dashboard you have general settings where you can put custom URL's like http://example.com/%caregory%/page_name

For more reference also checkhttp://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

I don't know if you tried this but after you login as admin, under Dashboard>>Settings>>Permalinks>>Custom Structure.

Let me know if you have already tried that.

Comment: I tried that and I doesn't work, I tried it and it just literally adds %category% to the url :(

Comment: This is for post only. Not for pages.